# Excel automation. Need to select multiple items from a Range

Tags: excel, automation, ole, dsoframer

I have code that lets me select a single item in arange:

```
        COleVariant vItems = cstrAddr;
        hr = AutoWrap(
                            DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, 
                            &vCell, 
                            irange, 
                            L"Item", 
                            2,
                            COleVariant((short)(1)), 
                            COleVariant((short)(1)));
        if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;


        // Use the dispatch interface to select the cell
        COleVariant result;
        hr = AutoWrap(
                        DISPATCH_METHOD, 
                        &result, 
                        vCell.pdispVal, 
                        L"Select", 
                        0);
        if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
```

This works fine.  However, I need to select all the cells in the range, but I haven't been able to find a way to specify this in the "get" call for the Item property.  Tried using -1,-1... tried passing in a pair of bstr in the 2 variants, specifying a colon separated range of columns and a range of rows;  also tried passing in a single parameter of a string of range specification.  None worked.

**Update**:  I have also tried

```
hr = iRange->Select(vResult);
```

This does return S_OK, but it does not select the range.  Normally, I can't directly call the functions in the iRange struct; the result is a gpf or access violation -- so I have to use the autowrap function (to drive an Invoke call).  I'm not surprised this call doesn't work.  Hope I can get this working.... it's the last piece of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question.  This only appears to be a problem when used in the DSOFRAMER sample (Microsoft KB 311765).  DSOFramer is a general purpose ActiveX control for embedding MS Office documents.  The problem also only happens in a debug build; release builds are fine.

I also found a workaround that works on release or debug build:  get any cell in the range  (using get_Item), then call select on that item, then select again to de-select it.  Once that's done, the select can be called on the range.  Apparently, select cannot be called on the range if there is a cell already selected (or perhaps if the selection state is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with that kind of code (in VB it's much, much easier to do Automation) I think in your example you are selecting one cell from a range using the Item property and the Select method. Correct?

So in VB

```
Dim oRange as Range
Dim oCell as Range

 Set oRange = WorkSheet.Range("A1:A10") '<-- get range
 Set oCell = oRange.Item(1)             '<-- returns first cell in range
 oCell.Select                           '<-- selects first cell
```

The problem is Item property only returns one cell - you have to apply the Select method to the original range.

```
Dim oRange as Range

 Set oRange = WorkSheet.Range("A1:A10") '<-- get range
 oRange.Select                          '<-- Selects the range
```

Comment: That's what I was originally trying to do. I get a failure when I make that call, however. HRESULT 0x800a03ec. I have a separate question posted here to address that one.

Comment: Also, I saw this page: http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcelnet/doc/NativeExcel.IRange.Select.html  which hints that from c++, you can specify a range on items.  Due to restrictions in my code, I can't use the classes listed there. I have to use the autowrap/invoke style calls.